# Alternate colors of GeoJSON linestring segments in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, style

I am rendering a vector linestring via GeoJSON on top of an OpenLayers map.  I'd like to alternate the styling between two slightly different shades of blue, such that the colors alternate from one line segment to the next.  Is there any way to do this, apart from using points instead of a linestring and constructing the line segments myself?

```
var path;

function drawPath(table, x, y, id) {
  var urlreq = "../grab.php?method=get_path&x=" + x + "&y=" + y + "&table=" + table +
                "&id=" + id;
  if( typeof(path) != 'undefined' ) { map.removeLayer(path); }
  path = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Path", {
    projection: epsg900913,
    style: {
      strokeColor: "blue",
      strokeWidth: 3
    },
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
      url: urlreq,
      format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    })
  });
  map.addLayer(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PointTrack layer. See my live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/hgCUq/1/light/).

I think code below helps you to understand how to build layer over requested data:

```
features = [];
json = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();

OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: "../grab.php?method=get_path&x=" + x + "&y=" + y + "&table=" + table + "&id=" + id",
    async: false,
    success: function(r){
        features = json.read(r.responseText);
    }
});

track_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.PointTrack('Track');
map.addLayer(track_layer);
track_layer.addNodes(features);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good example. When I use your approach of manually adding a set of points to a vector layer, it works to do addNodes on those features (they appear on the map). When I try to use my "path" layer with addNodes (e.g., track.addNodes(path.features) ), the pointTrack is not drawn on the map.  Are those features not accessible in the same way when using the strategy/protocol AJAX approach?

Comment: I've modified my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see...a GET request with async off.  Thanks very much!